# Передача строки в функцию в Си

Tags: c, stm32

Это код для STM32F030, он компилируется без ошибок, но если залить этот код в микроконтроллер - он даже не запускается. Подскажите, сам код написан правильно?

```
void print(char * string)
{
    while(*string)
    {
        while(!(USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1, USART_FLAG_TXE)));
        USART_SendData(USART1, *string++);
    }
}


int main (void)
{
    Init_Clock();
    Init_USART1();
    print("Hello World!");
    while(1);
}
```

Почему всё работает нормально, если вызвать функцию вот так:

```
char hello[] = {"Hello World!"};

print(hello);
```

Как правильно передать строку в функцию?

Comment: С контроллерами дел не имел, но с точки зрения чистого языка - разница в том, что в первом случае вы передаете указатель на литерал, который не изменяем (представляет собой `const char*`), а во втором - вполне изменяем. Попробуйте интереса ради объявить `print(const char*)`. Еще раз - в контроллерах я не смыслю; комментирую только с точки зрения чисто языка как такового.

Comment: Мне и нужно с точки зрения языка как такового) Хочу понять, это я коряво пишу или особенность микроконтроллера.  const пробовал - код ведёт себя точно так же

Comment: Вы скомпилируйте оба варианта так, чтобы компилятор Вам вывел ассемблерный листинг. И сравните ассемблерные листинги для обоих вариантов. Сразу все станет понятно.

Comment: Скорее всего во втором варианте строка расположена на стеке и инициализируется константой из секции кода. А в первом варианте строка расположена в секции кода в константах. То есть имеется какая-то проблема с доступом к константам в коде. Транслятор-то какой? GCC или самодельный от фирмы-производителя контроллера? А, вижу. Контроллер ARM так что транслятор скорее всего GCC. Это странно. GCC для ARM хорошо отлажен, там не должно быть таких очевидных косяков.

Comment: Еще проверьте под тот ли тип ядра ARM у Вас компилируется код. Похоже, что указатель string как-то с ошибкой ползает по константным строкам, но без ошибок ползает по строкам, расположенным в памяти или на стеке.

Comment: Тип ядра точно тот: в IDE при создании проекта нужно точно указать модель микроконтроллера, для которого пишется код

Comment: [Подскажите, сам код написан правильно?] Если код компилируется, значит он написан правильно. Во всяком случае для GCC это почти всегда так. Тем более в таком простом случае. Тут что-то системное, какой-то косяк в настройках, а не собственно в коде.

Comment: Вот еще что. Попробуйте написать вызов вот так: print((char*)"Hello World!");

Comment: Попробовал, никаких изменений

Comment: Тогда попробуйте сравнить ассемблерные листинги для двух вариантов. Там будет видно, в чем разница. То есть в чем разница в ассемблерных конструкциях, в которые транслятор разворачивает два варианта кода.

Comment: Спасибо за участие, оказалось, проблема не в коде, а в компиляторе или самом чипе. Если интерено - подробно расписал [тут](http://forum.cxem.net/index.php?/topic/204393-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-uart-%D0%B2-stm32f030/)

Comment: @User_0 Так что же, дело было в выравнивании что-ли? Что-то сомнительно. Компилятор знает, если у камня есть проблемы с доступом по нечетным адресам и компилятор должен располагать данные так, чтобы камень мог до данных добраться.

Comment: @User_0 Вот еще что может быть. Доступ к флеш-памяти кода в несколько раз дольше по времени, чем доступ к ОЗУ. Может быть банально флеш не успевает отвечать? То есть если строка лежит во флеш-памяти кода, то первое чтение же читает ноль и ничего не выводится. В таких чипах есть параметр - задержка чтения при доступе к флеш-памяти кода. Может быть покрутить этот параметр?

Comment: Нет, дело не в выравнивании (то есть не только в нём). Если передавать в функцию строку длиной 3+4n, где n - целое число - всё работает. Например, если в исходном примере "Hello World!" заменить на "Hello World" (то есть убрать один символ) - всё работает. Точно так же всё работает если, наоборот, добавить три любых символа. Значит скорость доступа к памяти ни при чём. Кажется, дело именно в выравнивании. Но в то же время я не выравнивал байты, я просто изменил одну команду - и всё заработало. Наверное, микроконтроллер некорректно обрабатывает ту команду, которую я заменил

Comment: @User_0 Здесь что-то не то. Причина в чем-то другом. Компилятор должен все знать про выравнивание, тем более если ему явно сообщают тип камня.

Comment: На данный момент можно сказать что проблема решена, но причина так и осталась не понятна, это верно. В какую сторону дальше копать?

Comment: @User_0 Если Вы и дальше будете работать с этим камнем, то рано или поздно поймете причину. Будете читать документацию по процессору и по компилятору и где-то там обязательно написано, почему так происходит.